# Встроенный ViewPager tablayout в Android

Tags: java, android, android-tablayout

Есть ли в андроиде `ViewPager` tablayout  из коробки? Не хочется тянуть либу для этого.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, встроенного нет. Надо или свой писать или библиотеку подключать.

Comment: а почему TabLayout(ом) не воспользоваться?

Comment: @TimurMukhortov, ну, это же табы, не индикатор) Имею в виду, что думаю, что ТС имеет в виду точки под страницами ViewPager-а

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю вам ничего не тянуть, а воспользоваться следующим кодом c `TabLayout` ([ссылка на офф. доку](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html)).

**tab_indicator_selected:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape
            android:innerRadius="0dp"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thickness="4dp"
            android:useLevel="false">
            <solid android:color="@color/globalPurpleLight"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**tab_indicator_default:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape
            android:innerRadius="0dp"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thickness="2dp"
            android:useLevel="false">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**tab_selector:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_indicator_selected"
        android:state_selected="true"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_indicator_default"/>
</selector>
```

**fragment_viewpager:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:gravity="center">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        .../>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabDots"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
        app:tabGravity="center"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Код в Activity/Fragment:**

```
MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(...);
myViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(myViewPager);
```

*Замечание: `@color/globalPurpleLight` - это мой цвет из файла `colors.xml`, можете задать свой.*